# Push file generated in ruby to git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, web

My app generates a yaml file in the directory lib/git, which I want to then push to git. I have tried to implement this like shown here https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git .

The following code gives me an Action Controller Exception at line `Git.init('lib/git',`.

```
g = Git.init
  Git.init('quota')
  Git.init('lib/git',
           { :repository => '/opt/git.git',
             :index => '/tmp/index'})

  saveProject do
    g.remote('add origin https://*************.git')
    g.config('user.name', '*************')
    g.config('user.email', '*************')

g.add(:all=>true)

g.commit(time)
g.push

end
```

How do I make this work?

EDIT:
The exact error is:  `'--git-dir=/opt/git.git' '--work-tree=lib/git' init 2>&1:/opt/git.git: Permission denied` 
How would I go about adding an ssh key to my app? That's also not in the docs.

Comment: Use [ssh keys](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/). In general, _never connect to git repo using passwords_.

Comment: Why do you have 3 git inits? Usually one is enough. That's probably why you are getting an error in second git init call.

Comment: *"The following code gives me an Action Controller Exception"* Please show us the actual error message. (Ideally with a reproducible code snippet so we can see exactly what caused it.)

Comment: I never bother with a lib for this. It is easy to interact with the command line in ruby.

Comment: @TomLord git '--git-dir=/opt/git.git' '--work-tree=lib/git' init   2>&1:/opt/git.git: Permission denied

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš I commented out the additional inits, but the error remains.